# Elasticsearch search for architects and show the results with architecture as well

Tags: elasticsearch

`{ "type": "DATA", "thumbnail": "dummp.webp", "name": "Test Trader Architects", "keywords": "Architecture", "tagged_services": [ { "id": 1, "name": "Architects" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Civil engineers" } ] } }`

i want to search for name, keywords and tagged_services with Architects keywords, and fetch the related results

```
`{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": " Architects",
                    "fields": [
                        "name",
                        "keywords",
                        "tagged_services"
                    ],
                    "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                }
            }
        ],
        "should": [
            {
                "match_phrase": {
                    "name": "Architects"
                }
            },
            {
                "match_phrase": {
                    "keywords": "Architects"
                }
            },
            {
                "match_phrase": {
                    "tagged_services": "Architects"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
"size": 10
```

}`

the above one i have used, but its not showing the result of tagged_services with Architects

Comment: What the mapping of your index? `tagged_services` in particular, if it's not `flattened` you cannot query the field like you do

Comment: "tagged_services": {
    "type": "object",
    "enabled": False
}

Answer (score 1):

Since `tagged_services` is an object you need to query it like this:

```
        {
            "match_phrase": {
                "tagged_services.name": "Architects"
            }
        }
```

However, since it's also configured with `enabled: false`, the data is not indexed, hence not queryable. You need to remove `enabled: false` and reindex your data in or der to query it.